# cross-referencing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, Chapters, SubChapters, and Divisions .  Each of these tables have additional records that I would like to store in a table called 'Sections'.  They are all 1:many relationships.
My question is what would be the best way to establish the cross reference here? This is what I currently have:

```
Chapter table:
     chapterID int
     partID int
     chapterNumber varchar
     chapterName varchar
SubChapter table:
     subChapterID int
     chapterID int
     subChapterNumber varchar
     subChapterName varchar
Division Table:
     divisionID int
     subChapterID int
     divisionNumber varchar
     divisionName varchar

Section Table:
     sectionID int
     parentID int
     parentType int (1 = chapter; 2 = subchapter; 3 = division)
     sectionNumber varchar
     sectionName varchar
```

The issue I'm running into here are FK restraints.  Should I just do away with the foreign keys?  What could I do to improve efficiency if I did or would that even be a concern?

For those wondering, my requirements are to have certain aspects of State and Federal administrative code accessible in a database to populate drop-down menus on the intranet webpages.

Comment: Why dont you just add a field `sectionType` (being chapter, subchapter, division or section) to the section table and put everything into that table?

Comment: I have to think a little more about the answer overall, but I wouldn't do away with FKs. That's sort of the point of having a relational database.

Comment: Matt: Foreign Keys are not the point of a relational database, tables and relationships are the point.  And FK's are *not* relationships, they are merely one way to physically implement the *enforcement* of a relationship, which is a very, very different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create a section table for each parent type and then your foreign keys would work properly. I would then create a view to join up all the joins to alleviate the repetitive nature of joining those six tables.

I can certainly appreciate the design you have now, but having the FKs make it nice in preventing orphaned data. Another alternative is to add delete triggers to Chapters, SubChapters, and Divisions to escape the deletion if there is a corresponding Sections record.

Comment: This was my original thought. So far, out of the administrative code that I need, none of them are formatted the same. In one instance, Louisiana, following your idea would take the 3 tables I have and turn it into 8 tables. 

What I am looking for is an alternative to using foreign keys.  I'm not experienced with database design, but for referencing the tables in programs, a design like this seems to be pretty easy.  If it helps, this is static data that if it changes will only be updated once a year.